# Query : Beeline interface in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, beeline

Beeline script is one of the way of connecting to HiveServer2 present in Spark/bin.

I ran simple query as below.

[image]

In output I can see Map-Reduce is being launched.

I am just trying to understand what is advantage of beeline feature in Spark as it follows traditional map-reduce execution framework?

Can we use Spark RDD feature in beeline?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's located at `/usr/lib/spark/bin/beeline` on EMR. You need to start the Thrift server: `sudo /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh` . It will be available on port 10001. Use `hadoop` username if required, no password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beeline is not part of Spark.

It's just a HiveServer2 client.

You can launch the Spark shell and execute queries within the shell, but this has nothing to do with Beeline. As Beeline has nothing to do with Spark.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way.If you dont want to use Mapreduce you can use `TEZ` as engine.Which will run in memory as more faster than MR.

```
SET hive.execution.engine=tez;
```

But you can not run spark ifrom beeline.This is a standalone application which connects to hiveserver2.